# TypeScript type in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have the following and I am learning TypeScript on the go,

```
interface Props {
  contentHeight: number,
  dayRender(
    date: Date, 
    el: HTMLElement, 
    view: object
  ): void,
...
```

dayRender is a custom function of the plugin I am using: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dayRender

and a component like so:

```
export class CalendarComponent extends Component<Props> {
  ...

  disableSaturday = ( slots: Array<{date: Date}> )  => {
    for(let i = 0; i < slots.length; i += 1) {
      if (getDay(slots[i].date) === Day.Sunday) {
        console.log(`it's saturday`)
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { 
      contentHeight,
      dateClick,
      defaultView,
      displayEventTime,
      header,
      selectedAvailablity: { endDate, slots, startDate }, 
      selectedDate 
    } = this.props

    this.goToDate(selectedDate)
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <FullCalendar
          contentHeight={contentHeight}
          // dayRender={'sth on day render'}
          dateClick={dateClick}
          defaultView={defaultView}
          displayEventTime={displayEventTime}
          events={slots}
          dayRender={this.disableSaturday}
          firstDay={Day.Monday}
          header={header}
          now={selectedDate}
          plugins={[dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
          ref={this.calendarRef}
          validRange={{
            start: startDate,
            end: endDate,
          }}
        />
      </Fragment>
    ...
```

I have updated the Props interfact and updated the type of dayRender but and I am getting a type error:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your `this.disableSaturday` function is not compatible with what `dayRender` expects:

`dayRender` expects to receive a function with the following props `{ view: View; date: Date; allDay?: boolean | undefined; el: HTMLElement; }`. But you gave it `this.disableSaturday` which wants `{ date: Date }[]` as props. `dayRender` can't do anything with that as `dayRender` can only provide 1 `{ date: Date }` object instead of an array of them.

To fix this you can simply do something like this:

```
dayRender(({ date }) => this.disableSaturday([date]))
```

The first date takes the **date** variable from dayRender. (destructuring).

The second part provides an array to `disableSaturday` with the 1 `date` variable in it.